# Wave Sort in O(n) time complexity

Tags: python, sorting

**Wave Sort** an array in time complexity **O(n)**

Wave sort sorts in array such that it forms a wave.
for ex: `3, 1, 4, 2, 8, 7` this would be the sorted array after applying wave sort

I expect the output of `3, 1, 4, 2, 8, 7` if input given is `1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 8`.
The outputs can differ based on implementation.
The main goal is to have a crest and trough in the array like a wave and do it in O(n).

Comment: Can you provide an exact definition of what you call "wave"?

Comment: Please add a tag for what language you want solutions in.

Comment: You get any input array. Then when sorted the number on the second spot should be greater than first and third place number. same with the 4th place number,

Comment: @HereticMonkey any language would have worked fine. thanks for trying to help but i found the solution. i've added it below

Comment: The tag for the question helps those who are trying to find an answer to the same question later. If they are looking to implement wave sort in JavaScript, your answer won't help them, since your answer is not, I believe, in JavaScript.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks heretic for letting me know. I edited :)

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate that you can achieve a "wave" sorted array from a linearly sorted array by simply walking down the array once, and swapping each pair of numbers encountered.  Using your sample input:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8
```

We can walk down the array and swap each pair of numbers, giving:

```
2, 1, 4, 3, 7, 8
```

The penalty for sorting the array using something like merge sort, or a comparable divide-and-conquer method, would be `O(N*lgN)`, where `N` be the size of the array.  On top of this, we would need a single `O(N)` operation to impose a wave sort.  So, the overall order can be:

```
O(N*lgN + N) = O(N*lgN)
```

Comment: so, the time complexity basically would be O(nlog(n)) not n. In the interview i was said to answer it in O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help. But i have found a solution that runs in **O(n)**.

```
def waveSort(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(0, n-1, 2):

        if i > 0 and a[i-1] > a[i]:
            a[i], a[i-1] = a[i-1], a[i]

        if i <= n-2 and a[i+1] > a[i]:
            a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]
    return arr
```

Heres the link to the complete file on github

[github.com/WaveSort](https://github.com/Joystick27/Ds-Algo/blob/master/WaveSort/WaveSort.ipynb)